# Short term grant for travel/relocation costs when starting a PhD

Tags: phd, funding, travel

I've been accepted into a PhD program in Bielefeld, and I'm also waiting on a response from ETH Zurich. The thing is, moving to either place from the Netherlands is expensive, and then I need to find a place and pay for deposit and administration costs, and furnishing if so. Does anyone know short term grants for starting students that I can use to fund my first month of PhD while I get my first pay check?

Comment: Are you indeed looking for a grant (somebody should give you money for this) or a short-term loan (somebody lends you money)? Because the second seems much more realistic and common than the former.

Comment: Have you asked the university? Maybe they can give your first salary in advance or help you with the housing.

Answer (score 3):

When I was in that exact same spot, my advisor managed to get me a temporary/emergency one month grant. Therefore, I'll repeat one of the mantras **talk to your advisor**...